# Remove windows XP after installing Ubuntu

Tags: 11.10, windows, partitioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to uninstall Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100965/how-to-uninstall-windows)

OK, I am kind of illiterate when it comes to computers.  I have a Gateway 6018GZ laptop which I loaded Ubuntu 11.10 on....It has 2 partitions; one has windows xp and the other ubuntu-how can I delete windows xp from it completely?

Answer (score 1):

GParted would probably be your easiest solution.  Just delete the NTFS partition and run update-grub.  Both would be need to run as root/via sudo.

Comment: This is definitely the best way to go, but the answer might be more helpful if you lay it out step-by-step and add some screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Run Ubuntu from an USB-Stick, run GParted and delete the Windows Partition. Then extend the Ubuntu Partitioin to the maximum size.
Probably you confused your bootloader with this, so you have to repair him by using the following commands:

```
sudo su
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
for i in dev proc sys dev/pts; do mount --bind /$i /mnt/$i; done
chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sda
update-grub
```

While you should replace sda1 with sda2 or three, depending where Ubuntu is installed (you see that in gparted)

Answer (score 0):

have you used it for long? If there is nothing you need on both OS you can just re install as only OS (insert disk or cd, boot, and click on install. One of the choices(for me) was along the lines of delete old OS and install over it)