# how to delete an operating system (windows) from my computer?

Tags: root, windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to uninstall Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100965/how-to-uninstall-windows)

I want to install XP in my computer with ubuntu. I can have two,. but if I want to delette windows XP and stay with ubuntu. how can I delete windows and stay with ubuntu without changes in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure you have grub installed as your bootloader.

Then make sure you have a backup copy of all your important files.

In the end just remove the Window partition with Gparted from a live system and then reboot with Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm not so practical. step by step?

Comment: The question was closed, I'm sorry :) Anyway if you google it there are a lot of things speaking of this ;)

Comment: don't be angry man sorry.