# Which one is the Windows Partition I want to delete in this GParted screenshot?

Tags: windows, dual-boot, delete

Basically I just got Ubuntu yesterday as a DualBoot.
I am trying to delete Windows Vista now.
I would have just got the USB install and just replaced Ubuntu with Windows but I kept getting errors.

I am following this guys instructions to delete Windows:
[How to uninstall Windows from a Dual Boot system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100965/how-to-uninstall-windows)

So I am at GParted,
and he says to delete the Windows Partition.
I have a feeling the 2nd one is the Windows Partition, but it's locked.
Here's the first picture:

[image]

The second Partition I can't delete, it is just gray over the delete button.

Please help me delete Windows!

Comment: That looks strange. Do you have two hard disk installed? Or is that started from the live stick?

Answer (score 5):

**Be very sure you are not using Wubi (installed Ubuntu from Windows) since your NTFS partition is called `/host`!!**
**And that you are on a Live-CD/USB!**

Both partitions are NTFS; the first one is a "diagnostic" partition from Toshiba, the second one is Windows. You may have to right-click and *Unmount* the partition in gray before GParted will let you delete it; if there is no Unmount option or you try unmounting and it fails, **you are probably using Wubi!**

Comment: Thanks also, I guess I'll end up getting the live CD after all.

Answer (score 2):

The second one is indeed your Windows partition. You will have to unmount this partition first by right-clicking and choosing "Unmount".

Besides, you should definitely take a look at "Disk Utility". It suits basic partitioning needs, has benchmarking, can deal with S.M.A.R.T info, RAID and LVM setups, and more. It's installed by default.

Edit: it seems like you are running a Wubi install, since your Windows partition is mounted on /host. In this case, the information above is irrelevant and you will have to reinstall Ubuntu "the real way" in order to achieve what you want.

This can be done by booting your computer from the Ubuntu live cd/usb.

Comment: Ahh thanks. Yeah, I am using Wubi. I guess I'll have to deal with DualBoot until I get the LiveCD.

Answer (score 0):

As I see your primary partition is /dev/sda2 with the ntfs filesystem and your system is booting on this partition , probably it's  "windows" that you're looking for.
Although /dev/sda1 is a partition for diagnostics or recovery but there is no mount point on.

To delete a partition : 
try to login as sudo and launch "cfdisk" to manage your partitions , then unmount your mount point on your last partition .

Answer (score 0):

As you don't have an ext2/3/4 partition - your Ubuntu installation is a Wubi installation which uses a virtual disk.
If you want a completely native Ubuntu installation you need a separate partition on disk for Ubuntu.

1. Unistall Ubuntu Wubi installation.
2. Use Vista to optimize disk space (so files are moved towards start of disk).
3. Use GParted from live DVD/USB to shrink existing Vista partition and create free space for Ubuntu installation.
4. Install Ubuntu to hard disk using the free space on disk. (Ubuntu will create one ext4 partition and a swap partition).

After Ubuntu is installed you will have a dual-boot Vista - Ubuntu.
Using GParted you can delete Vista partition and then update grub configuration so you end up in a single boot for Ubuntu.

You can keep "TOSHIBA SYSTEM VOLUME" or delete it (it contains maybe some recovery tools but it does not contain full recovery of Vista as only ~500 MB are used).