# Making Ubuntu my default OS

Tags: windows, default

I recently installed Ubuntu, which instead of eliminating windows, it partitioned it. My question is first how to make Ubuntu my default OS?

Secondly, how do I remove windows to speed up the computer?

---

this is NOT the grub I am talking about, rather the partitions you have to chose between before you enter the grub. Right now if I am not right at the computer when the partitions Windows Xp and Ubuntu pops up, it will automatically go to Windows. I want it to automatically choose Ubuntu instead. The grub is here it goes to once I enter the Ubuntu partition. The settings there is fine. I need it to open Upuntu automatically.How do I do that. Sorry, I can't explain it better then that, Im not as knowlegable as y'all.

Comment: Removing Windows will not speed up the computer unless you are out of disk space. There are many ways to speed up the computer including changing some of them including changing the animations that are happening, adding more memory or adding a faster processor

Comment: What do you mean when you say *make Ubuntu my default OS*?

Comment: possible duplicated: http://askubuntu.com/q/100965/62483

Comment: Well the reason you might think removing windows would speed up booting is that you could skip GRUB for OS boot selection but this actually has much more purpose than that as it allows for recovery for Ubuntu and some other options for memory testing.

If you wish to remove windows completely then it is an option you missed at install time to erase the entire disk and install Ubuntu.

Comment: Lucio - I mean make Ubuntu my default. Right now if I am not right at the computer when it fires up it will open Windows. I want it to open Ubuntu by default.
 
brim4brim & jjesse okay I don't have to remove windows if I can make Ubuntu my default.

Answer (score 0):

If you use wubi if you have installed it from windows, removing windows would be too advanced.
Your best option in this case would be to copy your home folder on a USB drive, And install it proper way using live installer on DVD or pen drive.

IF you want to play and keep the old setting:
after installing do not reboot yet if you if you have created same users as before,
check their user ids in new home folder (usually 500 for first user)

simply copy the old ones from USB key where you have backed them up into your new /home and change the  user ids on them **including their subdirectories**

If you get access permission problems, you haven't set the ids right or only set it for main folder not inside. go back to liveDVD and change uids... on all directories in home folder including inside

make sure windows stays on a **first partition**!!!

If you have installed it proper way, removing windows wont speed computer up except if you are running out of space

first check which of the grub entries is the ubuntu
open your favorite editor using `sudo`

```
gksu mousepad

gksu gedit
```

Open `/etc/default/grub`:

Change the

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
```

number  to  the number of entry for Ubuntu.
run `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Lucio - I mean make Ubuntu my default. Right now if I am not right at the computer when it fires up it will open Windows. I want it o open Ubuntu by default.

Comment: the question stands. have you instaled ubuntu from windows (using wubi or by using liveCD (usb)?
if second one do the think about Grub I have wrote

Comment: brim4brim &  jjesse okay I don't have to remove windows if I can make Ubuntu my default.            Tomas yes I did...no I didn't have a live CD/memory stick.

Comment: then for you best option is to make new fresh install by booting from live CD and do the first part of answer

Comment: Running graphical applications as root using `sudo` is not recommended. Use `gksu` instead.

Comment: okay thanks guys...but what is sudo and gksu?

Comment: If you want to do something on a computer (rather then user) level on some Linux distribution you are using sudo in terminal. gksu is just more advanced option if you are opening graphical program(solves some issues between who is who).

Comment: Ok I finally figured out how to access wht y'all been talking about. However, this is NOT the grub I am talking about, rather the partitions you have to chose between before you enter the grub. Right now if I am not right at the computer when the partitions Windows Xp and Ubuntu pops up, it will automatically go to Windows. I want it to automatically choose Ubuntu instead. The grub is here it goes to once I enter the Ubuntu partition.  The settings there is fine. I need it to open Upuntu automatically.How do I do that. Sorry, I can't explain it better then that, Im not as knowlegable as y'all.

Comment: I still don't understand.  HOW do get ubuntu to be the default. Download from internet...Installed have two partitions....when I make changes listed above it will still go to windows unless I say otherwise.  However, when I choose ubuntu then the changes affect the grub which is after I am asking about.  Sorry I am a novice, but I was told you all would be willing to help us novices. So far all I've gotten is confusion.