# WUBI error after installation on Windows 8 laptop

Tags: dual-boot, wubi, windows-8

I try to install Ubuntu on a Laptop which actually runs with Windows 8.

After the Installation and restart, it´s this Error:

```
\ubuntu\wubildr.mbr

staus: 0x0000076
```

Comment: What *version* of Ubuntu are you trying to install? *Where*, *when* and *how* did you get that message?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 Bit

Comment: the Installation was complete, after restart I get this error

Comment: its about the File is not complete...sorry, I can not gif you the exact Quote becouse its in german...

Comment: Did you read [Installing on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/q/221835/65926)?

Comment: ok, seems realy complicated...I don´t realy Need Dual-Boot, isn´t it possible to delete Windows 8 and just install Ubuntu 12?

Comment: Yes, you can, just [remove Windows](http://askubuntu.com/q/100965/62483) and then [install Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/q/6328/62483).

Comment: Don't forget that you can [report your issue as a bug](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug). It will help all the community :)

Comment: So I just have to uninstall Windows and the install Ubuntu with a boot-DVD and than it has to work?

Comment: Wubi and Windows 8 don't behave at all.  This is a ***known issue*** and is one of the reasons Wubi was dropped from 12.10 and 13.04.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a ***known incompatibility between Windows 8 and Wubi*** which is behind Wubi being dropped from 12.10 images and 13.04.