# Delete one of the OS via Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows

I'm currently running on dual boot (win 7 and ubuntu). I'd like to know how to delete my Windows 7 OS using ubuntu

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to uninstall Windows from a Dual Boot system?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/100965/how-to-uninstall-windows-from-a-dual-boot-system)

Answer (score 2):

Hi and welcome to askubuntu,

I assume that you have a ubuntu live cd or usb in hand. The simplest and safest way would be to use OS-Uninstaller, a easy to use GUI tool which helps you uninstall any Operating System installed on your system with one click.But, please note that, you should install OS-Uninstaller on ubuntu live.
To install this tool, open up your terminal(Ctrl + Alt + T) on ubuntu live and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
```

Press Enter and type :

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install -y os-uninstaller && os-uninstaller
```

Press Enter once again and OS-Uninsaller will be installed on your system.

Now open OS-Uninstaller(onen the dash and type OS-Uninstaller).
You will now see a window showing all Operating Systems installed on your system. Choose the one you want to remove (Windows 7 in your case) and click "OK". A confirmation window will appear, click "Apply" on that.

You can find the detailed documentation of OS-Uninstaller here : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller
Hope it helps!

Comment: Doesn't work without a Live System.

Comment: Yes, OS-Uninstaller has to be installed in the live system.

Comment: You should add this to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

- Graphical with "gparted". You can install it from Ubuntu software center. You can ONLY edit partitions that are not active (Windows from Ubuntu will not be so you are OK there). [Otherwise create a bootable gParted DVD](http://gparted.org/) (always handy when you have one around)
- From command line you can do this with the command "parted".