# Os-Uninstaller will not work

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, updates

So I’m having an issue when every time i attempt to run os-uninstaller it gives me an error saying:

```
Please use this software in a live-session
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Comment: maybe also [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](http://askubuntu.com/q/221835/65926)

Comment: This is not strictly a duplicate of the above linked questions. However, they do contain explanation on how to boot into live session.  In addition, refer to [this question here](http://askubuntu.com/q/633088/295286)

Answer (score 0):

You must use it from a LiveCD, and not on your installed system.